# How to connect socket admin UI with nestjs backend

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I want to configure the admin ui in nestjs backend with socket but it giving cors error even after adding cors origin. please help what is wrong or i am missing.

```
import { OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  MessageBody,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
  OnGatewayInit
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { instrument } from '@socket.io/admin-ui';

import { Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway(undefined, {
  cors: { origin: ['https://admin.socket.io'], credentials: true }
})
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnModuleInit {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  afterInit() {
    instrument(this.server, {
      auth: false
    });
  }

  onModuleInit() {
    this.server.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log('client connected', socket.id);

      socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
        console.log(`disconnect ${socket.id} due to ${reason}`);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me

```
@WebSocketGateway(5002, {
  cors: {
    origin: ['https://admin.socket.io', 'http://localhost:3000'],
    credentials: true
  },
})
```

the only difference between out code is that i am using "development" mode

```
  afterInit() {
      instrument(this.server, {
        auth: false,
        mode: "development",   
      });
  }
```

Comment: thank for the reply. Yeah after passing port number it working fine.

and in server url of admin pannel no need to pass the /admin part